# one dimensional array in python

Tags: python, arrays, dimensions

Trying to run a simple linear regression model to predict price of a car with the highway-mpg given in the data. As I put them in the linear model function, python says that its getting a 1D answer whereas a 2D is expected. How do I fix this. I am not able to get the concept of (-1,1) and (1,-1) as given in the error by python.

```
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-f4055173756b> in <module>()
----> 1 lm.fit(x,y)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    480         n_jobs_ = self.n_jobs
    481         X, y = check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse=['csr', 'csc', 'coo'],
--> 482                          y_numeric=True, multi_output=True)
    483 
    484         if sample_weight is not None and np.atleast_1d(sample_weight).ndim > 1:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    571     X = check_array(X, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite,
    572                     ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples,
--> 573                     ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    574     if multi_output:
    575         y = check_array(y, 'csr', force_all_finite=True, ensure_2d=False,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    439                     "Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if "
    440                     "your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) "
--> 441                     "if it contains a single sample.".format(array))
    442             array = np.atleast_2d(array)
    443             # To ensure that array flags are maintained

ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[27 27 26 30 22 25 25 25 20 22 29 29 28 28 25 22 22 20 53 43 43 41 38 30
 38 38 38 30 30 24 54 38 42 34 34 34 34 33 33 33 33 28 31 29 43 43 29 19
 19 17 31 38 38 38 38 23 23 23 23 32 32 32 32 42 32 27 39 25 25 25 25 18
 18 16 16 24 41 38 38 30 30 32 24 24 24 32 32 30 30 37 50 37 37 37 37 37
 37 37 37 34 34 22 22 25 25 23 25 24 33 24 25 24 33 24 25 24 33 24 41 30
 38 38 38 30 24 27 25 25 25 28 31 31 28 28 28 28 26 26 36 31 31 37 33 32
 25 29 32 31 29 23 39 38 38 37 32 32 37 37 36 47 47 34 34 34 34 29 29 30
 30 30 30 30 30 34 33 32 32 32 24 24 24 24 46 34 46 34 34 42 32 29 29 24
 38 31 28 28 28 28 22 22 28 25 23 27 25].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

Answer (score 0):

Scikit-learn expect the input to be of shape (n_samples, n_features). In terms of lists this would be `[[x_11, ..., x_1N], ..., [x_M1, ..., xMN]]`, with `M = n_samples` and `N = n_features`
If you put in an 1D array (or just a single list), it doesn't know if you have 1 sample with n_features or n_samples with 1 feature. So if you transform your list/array `x` with

```
x_2d = np.asarray(x).reshape(-1, 1)
```

It will transform your array of shape (n_samples, ) to (n_samples, 1). The `(-1,1)` in reshape basically says that the last axis should be of size 1 and the first axis should have a size that doesn't change the total size of the array.